# Chrome extension authentication

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension

I'm having some difficulty implementing my first Chrome Extension. I don't have much experience using JavaScript and HTTP so please be forgiving if I'm making no sense.

The chrome extension can be found [here](https://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Playground/AnimeRatings/ChromePlugin) and contains three files: `addratings.js`, `icon.png` and `manifest.json`.

The `addratings.js` looks like this:

```
var http = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
http.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(http));
  }
}
var url = "http://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=Madoka";
http.open('GET', url, true);
http.send();
```

The `manifest.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Anime Ratings",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Shows anime ratings next to anime titles in a Web page.",
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "http://myanimelist.net/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "matches": ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_of_2011"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["addratings.js"]
    } ]
}
```

When I run the script (it is triggered when going to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aAnime_of_2011)) the http response I receive looks like this:

```
{"statusText":"Unauthorized","responseText":"Invalid credentials","response":"Invalid credentials","onabort":null,"readyState":4,"upload":{"onloadstart":null,"onabort":null,"onerror":null,"onload":null,"onprogress":null},"onerror":null,"status":401,"responseXML":null,"onprogress":null,"onload":null,"withCredentials":false,"onloadstart":null,"responseType":""}
```

I captured my HTTP request with Wireshark and confirmed that the 'Authorization' HTTP header was missing. Which explains the error message.

However, after reading [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) I was under the expression that the authorization header should have been included in the request because I added the domain to the manifest.json file.

So how do I provide the authentication headers to this http request?

Answer (score 2):

Move your XMLHttpRequest code from `addratings.js` to a background page. Use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) to communicate between a content script and a background page (to tell background page which search to execute and receive results back).